# ¿Por qué al insertar un dato en campo tipo checbox en PHP, me inserta NULL en el campo en lugar de los parametros otorgados?

Tags: php, mysql

Este es el código que uso para capturar los datos desde el siguiente input:

```
html += '<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="comedicion[]" value="1" />
```

Código para insertar capturado por medio de POST y luego pasa por ciclo for para agregar los datos tomados de cada campo seleccionado, lo que necesito es que el campo comedicion, me mande cero si no está marcado y uno si lo marco, pero me está mandando NULL a la BD.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['hidden_id'])){          
     $clasificacion     = $_POST['clasificacion'];
     $oc_bionexo        = $_POST['oc_bionexo'];
     $fecha_orden       = $_POST['fecha_orden'];
     $proveedor_compra  = $_POST['proveedor_compra'];
     $cant_comprada     = $_POST['cant_comprada'];
     $justificacion     = $_POST['justificacion'];
     $user_compras      = $_POST['user_compras'];
     $comedicion        = $_POST['comedicion']; // Opción 1 no funciona
     $comedicion = (isset($_POST["comedicion"])) ? (($_POST["comedicion"] == "on") ? 0 : 1) : 1; // opción 2 no funciona
     $comedicion = empty($_POST['comedicion']) ? 0 : 1; // Opción 3 no funciona

     $id                = $_POST['hidden_id'];


     for($count = 0; $count < count($id); $count++)
     {
      $data = array(
       ':clasificacion'     => $clasificacion[$count],
       ':oc_bionexo'        => $oc_bionexo[$count],
       ':fecha_orden'       => $fecha_orden[$count],
       ':proveedor_compra'  => $proveedor_compra[$count],
       ':cant_comprada'     => $cant_comprada[$count],
       ':justificacion'     => $justificacion[$count],
       ':user_compras'      => $user_compras[$count],
       ':comedicion'        => $comedicion[$count],
       ':id'                => $id[$count]
      );
```

[image: Así llega el dato]

Comment: Si utilizaras JS, recuperas el conjunto de checkbox, validas el seleccionado y ya lo mandas a tu PHP con tu VALOR sea 0 o 1, pero con puro PHP creo no es correcto. Te puedes guiar aquí, yo hice algo parecido: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167899/validar-si-hay-uno-o-varios-checkbox-seleccionados-en-javascript](http://Si%20utilizaras%20JS,%20recuperas%20el%20conjunto%20de%20checkbox,%20validas%20el%20seleccionado%20y%20ya%20lo%20mandas%20a%20tu%20PHP%20con%20tu%20VALOR%20sea%200%20o%201,%20pero%20con%20puro%20PHP%20creo%20no%20es%20correcto.%20Te%20puedes%20guiar%20aqui:%20https://es.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Validar si hay uno o varios checkbox seleccionados en Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167899/validar-si-hay-uno-o-varios-checkbox-seleccionados-en-javascript)

Comment: Gracias, estuve mirando pero no tengo tantos conocimientos para hacerlo de esa manera, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Pregunta: ¿ Te es necesario almacenar el dato del checkbox?

Si es que si, comprueba que estas referenciando bien la variable desde php porque por lo que leo estas referenciando "comedicion" no el array "comedicion[]"

Si no quieres los datos así o no sabes como te están llegando los datos, haz un "var_dump($_POST);" y comprueba que todo te está llegando como tu querrías.

Comment: Bueno, solo necesito que a mi BD en el campo llegue 0 o 1, nada mas.

Comment: Prueba a poner en el formulario name="comedicion" en vez de name="comedicion[]

Comment: Aclaraciones sobre la pregunta se realizan como comentarios, revisar [answer],saludos.

Comment: Gracias Oscar, ya hice lo que me dijiste pero tengo el mismo resultado, incluso si marco el chekbox, me manda NULL al campo comedicion.